# While running a topology in storm we are getting error like this

Tags: apache-storm

While running a topology in storm we are getting error like this,

```
8983 [Thread-6] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl -
Starting
9144 [main] INFO  **backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus** - Shutting down master
9199 [Thread-6-EventThread] INFO  backtype.storm.zookeeper - Zookeeper state upd
ate: :connected:none
9241 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Shut down master
9273 [Thread-6] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl -
Starting
9306 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.serv
er.NIOServerCnxn - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from cli
ent sessionid 0x143af55728d0003, likely client has closed socket
9354 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Shutting down c094c3b1-a378
-4c4f-af35-9278647c217a:4beddc09-4675-4fb9-8bdc-9cf5013ce9ca
9358 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Shut down c094c3b1-a378-4c4
f-af35-9278647c217a:4beddc09-4675-4fb9-8bdc-9cf5013ce9ca
9361 [main] INFO  **backtype.storm.daemon.superviso**r - Shutting down supervisor c0
94c3b1-a378-4c4f-af35-9278647c217a
9364 [Thread-5] INFO  **backtype.storm.event** - Event manager interrupted
9369 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
9425 [main] INFO  **backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor** - Shutting down supervisor 38
6d8d71-c9b5-4b51-bd6e-f9f605034ea0
9428 [Thread-8] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
9429 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.serv
er.NIOServerCnxn - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from cli
ent sessionid 0x143af55728d0007, likely client has closed socket
9429 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
9473 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.serv
er.NIOServerCnxn - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from cli
ent sessionid 0x143af55728d0009, likely client has closed socket
9476 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Shutting down in process zookeeper
9503 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.serv
er.NIOServerCnxn - Ignoring exception
**java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException**: null
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.jav
a:211) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$Factory.run(NIOServerCnxn.j
ava:242) ~[zookeeper-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3-1073969]
9510 [main] INFO  **backtype.storm.testing** - Done shutting down in process zookeep
er
9513 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\sowm
iya\AppData\Local\Temp\c9b1bc1a-a950-4098-af77-f81a4d2b112f
9520 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\sowm
iya\AppData\Local\Temp\7e75c468-18ea-4787-a4ac-496fb108db71
9527 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Unable to delete file: C:\Users\sowmi
ya\AppData\Local\Temp\7e75c468-18ea-4787-a4ac-496fb108db71\version-2\log.1
9529 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\sowm
iya\AppData\Local\Temp\fa7b3c9b-ac93-4090-b9e2-63f10019e61f
9543 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\sowm
iya\AppData\Local\Temp\55f1fd11-508e-43bb-b340-0d9b79f3af33
9579 [Thread-6-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.Connection
StateManager - State change: SUSPENDED
9580 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.Connec
tionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
9583 [Thread-6-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :disco
nnected::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
11232 [Thread-6-SendThread(localhost:2000)] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnx
n - Session 0x143af55728d000b for server null, unexpected error, closing socket
connection and attempting reconnect
**java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information**
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_0
3]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701
) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
~[zookeeper-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3-1073969]
13992 [Thread-6-SendThread(localhost:2000)] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnx
n - Session 0x143af55728d000b for server null, unexpected error, closing socket
connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_0
3]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701
) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
```

Whwn we are trying to run the topology jar file all the operation like nimbus,zookeeper and supervisor process going to dead.please help us to know why this is happened.
Please help us to rectify this error and help to proceed further.
Thank you,
Sowmiya
Priya

Comment: Can't help without knowing the source code of your topology

Comment: Can you share your topology code?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a zookeeper issue.  It looks like your processes are not being able to connect to zookeeper.  Can't say more without more information.